# xfreerdp (sometimes) doesn't connect for various reasons

Tags: xfreerdp

I run my workstation on Linux Mint 17.2. I have a Windows 2012 server VM I connect to when I need to do windows work. I use the following script:

```
xfreerdp +clipboard /u:<username> /p:<password> +nego +sec-rdp +sec-tls \
    +sec-nla /gt:rpc /w:1919 /h:1030 /v:<FQDN>
```

At least a little over half the time it works ok, and I connect right up. But frequently it doesn't connect and instead gives me one of several errors. The main one I seem to get is

```
[12:45:20:655] [26192:26193] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.nla] - SPNEGO failed with NTSTATUS: 0xC000006D
[12:45:20:655] [26192:26193] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - freerdp_set_last_error Unknown error class [0xC000006D]
[12:45:20:655] [26192:26193] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.rdp] - rdp_recv_callback: CONNECTION_STATE_NLA - nla_recv_pdu() fail
[12:45:20:655] [26192:26193] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.transport] - transport_check_fds: transport->ReceiveCallback() - -1
[12:45:20:655] [26192:26193] [ERROR][com.freerdp.client.x11] - Freerdp connect error exit status 1
```

doing some interwebbing, it seems like this is a "bad password" error or possibly a bad DNS entry. I've verified that the VM is using the same IP address that the DNS is resolving to so I don't think that's it.
When I remove the password parameter from my script and enter the password manually, it also fails. Needless to say I've entered the password correctly. So it appears xfreerdp is garbling the password somehow in transmission?
I have a coworker who uses the same setup as I (except scripts), and he does not have these problems. So either there is something wrong with my machine or my script.

Thanks for any help

EDIT: wrong version of windows

Comment: Still having this problem, although thanks for my second tumbleweed badge. :-/

Comment: I redeployed to a new Windows 10 instance and it works reliably now. It seems to be a transient problem with server 2012